# Woocomerce - Update max quantity for product variation

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product-quantity, product-variations

I'm trying to update max quantity for all variations of my variable product to ie 345.

```
$available_variations = $product->get_available_variations();


foreach ($available_variations as $variation) 
{ 
$variation_ID = $variation->ID;
update_post_meta( $variation_ID , 'max_qty', 345 );

}
```

It doesn't happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not using the correct way to get the variation ID and the product meta key `max_qty` doesn't exist in WooCommerce database on `wp_postmeta` table for `product_variation` post type.

Instead you can use the following filter hook to set a specific maximum quantity to product variations:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_available_variation', 'wc_available_variation_max_qty', 10, 3 );
function wc_available_variation_max_qty( $data, $product, $variation ) {
    $data['max_qty'] = 345;

    return $data;
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and work.

Comment: Thank you! I opted myself for database update since I couldn't find way to do it this way. Do you think this is better solution, performance wise?

Comment: @dejan This is a lighter solution, as there is no additional database request made by php on each product.

Answer (score 0):

Why not set it to 345 by default?

```
$max_m = $max_l = $max_xl = $max_xxl = $max_xxxl = '345';

if($max_qty != 345){
   //Limit Reached error
}
```

OR

```
$product->get_available_variations = '345';
if($variation_ID != 345){
    $variation_ID->max_qty = 345;
}
```

Since it's an online shop why not use MySQLi? It's PHP powered so why not?
this way you can do MySQLi->query, and UPDATE the value.

*Edited*

Comment: Sorry, you didn't understand my. I have variable product, which has 5 variations of size: M, L, XL, XXL, and XXL. When I open this product in my shop, I want to have quantities for each variation set to 345, which means I have M size 345 in stock, L size 345 in stock ...

Comment: I just used 345 as example. I'm fetching quantity with web api. It won't be 345 in any case i suppose.

Comment: I don't think PHP is something you might want to heavily rely on for that maybe go for javascript since you said you're using an API, but as I said before you should go for a database it just makes life easier.